# Set up Tor as internal Network

Tags: relays, network-configuration, directory, server-administration

My company is looking to use Tor internally for our network, using our own directory authority server, and would like to know if it's possible and how to do it

Bonus points if we could use it for private external access

Comment: [Run Your Own Tor Network](https://ritter.vg/blog-run_your_own_tor_network.html) briefly describes the whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My company is looking to use Tor internally for our network, using our own directory authority server, and would like to know if it's possible and how to do it

First of all, if your company have the ability to monitor all trafic, then your Tor network becomes useless, since it's going to be really easy to tell who is doing what.

But if your company can't do that, you need to dedicate a server for Directory authority, make sure it's IP is static and is maintains a good uptime. Also, it should be strongly protected from unauthorized access (latest updates, using [ssh public key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication), keeping sshs's private keys secure and so on).

Making Tor nodes use it is really simple. Use `DirAuthority` option in `torrc` config file to set it up and thats it!

You need a minimum of 3 tor nodes, one of which is an exit (I recommend using at least 9). Try to keep the amount of exit nodes proportionate to the amount of middle and guard nodes. The more tor nodes you add, the harder it becomes to perform [end-to-end confirmation attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147402/how-do-traffic-correlation-attacks-against-tor-users-work), because you need to monitor a lot more computers for it.

> Bonus points if we could use it for private external access

You can setup some kind of proxy for that purpuse and use it from Tor.